# Excel 2010 vba Workbook methods using variables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

When path and filename arguments are explicitly defined as in the code below, the execution succeeds.
If path and filename arguments are variables ( as shown in the commented-out code lines below ) the code fails 
with error "Runtime error 1004 and shows  at statement "Workbooks.Open LatestTestBk" -

```
'Get the test Peak Value and add to Test Data row for this test
 Dim PeakValue, LatestTestBk

 Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live    
 Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx"
 'LatestTestBk = FileDestination & NewFileName
'Workbooks.Open LatestTestBk
 PeakValue = Workbooks("Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-
  AM.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("E1").End(xlDown)
'Workbooks(NewFileName).Close
 Workbooks("Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx").Close
 Worksheets("Job Data").Cells(30, 1) = PeakValue
```

What am I missing trying to use variables for the path and filename arguments?  Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: show please value of your variables: `FileDestination` and `NewFileName`

Comment: FileDestination = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live    
 Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx"   and    NewFileName = "Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-
  AM.xlsx"

Comment: ok, than `LatestTestBk` would be  `C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsxLive Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26- AM.xlsx` - whitch is wrong ( since `Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26- AM.xlsx` repeats two times)

Comment: I agree with your analysis.  My post of the FileDestination value was wrong.  It is actually   C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\   Sorry for the mistake in my post.  I tried to add a screenshot of the Watch window with the runtime values but was blocked due to not enough Reputation points to be allowed.  I am very new to StackExchange.

Comment: you can edit your post with a _link_ to your screenshot (say, using https://www.dropbox.com)

Comment: just tested your code and it works for me..can you add `MsgBox LatestTestBk` in your code just before this line `Workbooks.Open LatestTestBk` and show screen as well:)

Comment: BTW, in your first comment you say that `NewFileName = "Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26- AM.xlsx"` - note there is additional space before `AM.xlsx`. Is it again "comment mistake" or you have wrong value? I sad it because in your `Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live    
 Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx"` there is no space before `AM.xlsx`

Comment: The space before AM.xlsx was also a typo.

Comment: note in your image, that your `LatestTestBk` has double back slash `\\ ` before `Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx` (see in watches window)

Comment: I am running the code in Excel 2010 32-bit on a Win7 64-bit PC.  Is there any problem with this?

Comment: I'd recommend you to ckeck what result would be for 1) `MsgBox LatestTestBk="C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx"` and 2)`MsgBox Trim(LatestTestBk)="C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\8888\CompletedTestfiles\Live Graph_02-07-14_9-11-26-AM.xlsx"`. Btw, is english is your local language? if not, check maybe you have, on letter in similar languages: say, `е` in one language, and `e` in engl are different

Comment: Thank you, simoco.  You put me on the solution.  The space at the end of the path and filename values was causing Excel to complain that it could not find the path or file.  I processed the values to eliminate the problem space and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, problem was in additional spaces in the file path. This works:

```
LatestTestBk = Trim(FileDestination) & Trim(NewFileName)
Workbooks.Open LatestTestBk
```

Answer (score 0):

Check *LatestTestBk* for any missing **BackSlashes**

Comment: No missing backslashes in the filename / path variables as indicated in Watches on those variables.  But I do notice that in the Watch window the values for LatestFileBk and NewFileName have a space before the closing quote.  This is not visible when viewing the values by hovering over the variable while the code is paused for the error.

Answer (score 0):

it fails as variables because of the spaces:

use instead:

```
"'" & VarName & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That resolved the problem.  Simoco put me on the right track with his last comment above.